# ¿Cómo hacer que la barra indicadora muestre su ancho automáticamente en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenga una barra indicadora donde me muestra 4 fases representadas por anchos, cada una con un respectivo color.

Cuando se coloca un número entre el `0` al `20` esta se mueve con su respectivo ancho. Para poder lograr esto coloque se colocó un botón `Enviar`.

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer que la barra automáticamente se mueva hasta el ancho respectivo tan solo colocando el número sin el botón `Enviar`?.

Mi código HTML es:

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="" id="bar1" role="progressbar" onclick="enviar(event)" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20"></div>
</div>
<form id="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputText22" class="col-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label text-left label-style">Valor Obtenido:</label>
      <div class="col-9 col-lg-9">
        <input id="inputText22" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers">
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="enviar(event)">
    Enviar
  </button>
</form>
```

El código javascript que hice para que logre moverse es:

```
function enviar(event){
    var valor_obtenido = document.getElementById('inputText22').value;
    var bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
    var width = 0;

    if(valor_obtenido >= 0 && valor_obtenido <= 2.35){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped";
        bar1.style.width = "15%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 2.35 && valor_obtenido <= 5.94){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success";
        bar1.style.width = "40%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 5.94 && valor_obtenido <= 8.44){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning";
        bar1.style.width = "60%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 8.44 && valor_obtenido <= 10){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-danger"
        bar1.style.width = "90%";
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

¿Cómo se podría modificar el `JavaScript` para que se mueve de acuerdo al número ingresado?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap ?

Comment: Si estoy usando bootstrap.

Comment: Bien, he creado la respuesta con mi planteamiento para resolver lo que pides.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo con el código.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como `Respuesta aceptada` con el `check` que esta debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es agregar el evento que tienes en el `click` a tu campo de texto con el evento `onkeyup` pero me parece que también quieres controlar el `submit` con este por lo que deberías dividir la lógica, mi planteamiento es el siguiente;

```js
function enviar(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}

function setProgress(){
    var valor_obtenido = document.getElementById('inputText22').value;
    var bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
    var width = 0;

    if(valor_obtenido >= 0 && valor_obtenido <= 2.35){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped";
        bar1.style.width = "15%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 2.35 && valor_obtenido <= 5.94){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success";
        bar1.style.width = "40%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 5.94 && valor_obtenido <= 8.44){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning";
        bar1.style.width = "60%";
    }else if(valor_obtenido >= 8.44 && valor_obtenido <= 10){
        bar1.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-danger"
        bar1.style.width = "90%";
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress">
  <div class="" id="bar1" role="progressbar" onclick="enviar(event)" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20"></div>
</div>
<form id="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputText22" class="col-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label text-left label-style">Valor Obtenido:</label>
      <div class="col-9 col-lg-9">
        <input id="inputText22" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" onkeyup="setProgress()" onchange="setProgress(event)">
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="enviar(event)">
    Enviar
  </button>
</form>
```

En lo que ves aca he creado una función llamada `setProgress` para establecer el progreso de la barra según corresponda, de igual manera agregue al campo de texto 2 eventos:

`onkeyup` para cuando se escriba manual el numero.

`onchange` para cuando se utilicen las flechas que proporciona la interfaz de usuario de los campos de tipo `number`.

En la cabecera he agregado el `CDN` de `Bootstrap` para poder ver el resultado.